# c# webservice call, buffer too small (Async?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, async-await

I have a ASP.NET Web API project which calls a service that is written in delphi. This connection works perfectly until the data stream that I am getting from the service gets too big (the delphi service is just reading some data from the database, so no files are being sent between them).

Now, of course I have increased the MaxBufferSize but at some point it gets ridiculous and now I am looking for a more sophisticated solution. So I came across async (every method that I have in my delphi service is also available as async, thanks Microsoft). But even when I call my function as async I still get an error when the data stream is bigger than the set buffer size (actually I don't get an error, the execution just stops at `await GetData`. 
So, is there a possibillity to process the data that I am getting from my service in chunks ? For example, I set the max size of the data stream, and the function keeps fetching  until I get all data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Async has nothing to do with buffer sizes or streaming.

> So, is there a possibillity to process the data that I am getting from my service in chunks?

Yes, this is what you need. All web service APIs that I know support streaming. WCF and HttpClient certainly do. A search for e.g. "httpclient stream response" should get you going.

Async IO is not needed here as far as I can tell from the information given.

Comment: But I am not going over http (not directly). I have the service object (I have embedded the service in my project) and through the object I can access functions. So you are saying that for this particular case I will have to rewrite my service connection  and I cannot use the service object but have to switch to http(client) and make the SOAP call "manually" ?

Comment: Are you using WCF right now? WCF supports streaming.

Comment: As I said, I have just used the possibility to add a service to my project (right click->add service reference to my project). I assume that WCF is used behind the scenes but in this particular case, when I add my service (which is written in delphi) i have a service object which I use to access my functions. But according to what you are saying, I will have to make those calls manually so I can use streaming (I didn't see this option on the service object I got when connected the service to my project)

Comment: OK, "Service References" are using WCF. If you want to avoid buffering then you need to use streaming. Search for "wcf streaming" to see how that's done. That should solve your problem. Workarounds would be to issue multiple calls with less data per call, or to transfer the data "out of band" for example using files.